# Changing BaseIntermediateOutputPath causes build error CS0103

Tags: msbuild, xamarin.forms

I have a simple .net standard project that included Xamarin.Forms in Visual studio 2017. The build was successful until I change the default BaseIntermediateOutputPath in project file.

Snippet of the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8</PackageTargetFallback>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>hello/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>   <!-- Comment this out and build passes -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

The build error was:

Page1.xaml.cs(17,4): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.

After inspecting the msbuild output. It looks like the XamlG target never included/executed.

Any insight?

Thanks.

C.

Comment: The exception 'InitializeComponent' doesn't make sense if it was hitting a problem with the BaseIntermediateOutputPath. That little exception snippet is pointing you to the class behind (Page1.Xaml.cs) being the problem. I'd double check that xamarin is attributing your 'Initialize' method inside of the constructor of 'Page1'. It's quite odd that removing that line in the xaml allows your app to build though.

Comment: Changing BaseIntermediateOutputPath to something other than obj/ causes xamarin.forms.target to not build .xaml files (the root cause). The InitializeComponents() method is generated by building the .xaml files, which creates .xaml.g.cs in the intermediate output path, and that get included in compile. the .xaml.g.cs (partial) class is the one that contains the Initializecomponents() method.